# How to add a project version to jira database with an external sql query

Tags: mysql, jira

When i insert using this sql:

```
INSERT INTO projectversion (ID, PROJECT, vname, DESCRIPTION, SEQUENCE, STARTDATE, RELEASEDATE)
    VALUES (10023, 10002, '1.1.1','mydescription',8, '2015-03-31 00:00:00', '2015-03-31 00:00:00');
```

It inserts a row to projectversion table properly, but i can not see it in projectversions in jira.

double checked project and version keys but jira does not show the project version that i have inserted with sql query.

Comment: My suggestion: "don't do it." A good rule of thumb is *never modify the JIRA database directly*. A lot of things in JIRA are cached (as evidenced by the fact that you need to restart to see your change) and there is a good chance that you will break something. Try using the JIRA CLI plugin or the REST API instead.

Comment: Its for one time solution for our migration process. Otherwise it is very dangerous as you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you restart the jira service it will appear.

Edit: If you open the page under "tools-system-indexing" path, and click Re-Index button your problem will be solved.

Comment: yes, you are right but i need a solution without restarting jira service.

Comment: I have transferred all releases from another db and restarted jira. and reindex them. thank you very much.